# Get the certain radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

have 5 radio button(yes or no) and I want to do is whenever I select 'Yes' either those buttons my textarea will color red, and I've already done that. but the problem is whenever I've select only one 'Yes' and change it to No the color of the textarea still remains on red

```
 $('.com_lease_checkbox').on("change", function() {
     console.log($(this).val());
     $(".com_lease_checkbox:checked").each(function(){
       // Check if the value is Yes
       if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'Yes') {
         // Set the color of text-area
         $('.com_lease_desc_a').css("border-color","red");
      }
     }); 
  });
```

Comment: It's very obviously because you've set the border color but havn't removed it from the other radio button.  It is not just going to remove the red border on its own.  An easier method would just to be set the border color in your css unless for some reason that is not an option.

Comment: Your version with ELSE will not work because if NO not the last one in the loop, it will go Green again

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do this is to Count How many selected 'No's .. if it's Zero it's OK else Red

```
 $('.com_lease_checkbox').on("change", function() {
      //var selectedYesCheckBoxesCount = $(".com_lease_checkbox[value='Yes']:selected").length;
      var selectedNoCheckBoxesCount = $(".com_lease_checkbox[value='No']:selected").length;

      if(selectedNoCheckBoxesCount > 0) {
            $('.com_lease_desc_a').css("border-color","red");
      } 
      else {
            $('.com_lease_desc_a').css("border-color","green");
      } 
 });
```